# How to prevent re-render with reselect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I'm trying to `reselect` middleware today and prevent unnecessary re-rendering.

Here is my reducer.js:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  dogs: 100,
  cats: 12312302384
};

const pets = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_DOGS":
      return {
        ...state, dogs: state.dogs + 1
      };
    case "CHANGE_CATS":
      return {
        ...state, cats: state.cats + 1
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default pets;
```

Here is my main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function ReduxDeneme(props) {
  // Selectors - Classic style - NON Memoized!
//   const dogsData = useSelector(state => state.pets.dogs);
//   const catsData = useSelector(state => state.pets.cats);

  //                          Dogs rendering..  --> First opening..
  // 10:11:28.070 index.js:18 CATS rendering.. --> First opening..
  // 10:11:29.703 index.js:13 Dogs rendering.. --> Press "ChangeDogs" button.
  // 10:11:29.703 index.js:18 CATS rendering..  --> Press "ChangeDogs" button.
  // 10:11:33.143 index.js:13 Dogs rendering.. --> Press "ChangeCats" button.
  // 10:11:33.143 index.js:18 CATS rendering..  --> Press "ChangeCats" button.

  // Selectors - Memoized version RESELECT middleware'i ile..
  const dogsDataMemo = createSelector(
    state => state.pets.dogs,
    dogs => dogs
  );
  const catsDataMemo = createSelector(
    state => state.pets.cats,
    cats => cats
  );

  const dogsData = useSelector(dogsDataMemo)
  const catsData = useSelector(catsDataMemo)


  // Components
  const Dogs = ({ dogsData }) => {
    console.log("Dogs rendering..");
    return <h1>{dogsData}</h1>;
  };

  const Cats = ({ catsData }) => {
    console.log("Cats rendering..");
    return <h1>{catsData}</h1>;
  };

  // Actions

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const changeDogs = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_DOGS" });
  const changeCats = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_CATS" });

  return (
    <div>
      <Dogs dogsData={dogsData} />
      <Cats catsData={catsData} />
      <button onClick={changeDogs}>Change Dogs</button>
      <button onClick={changeCats}>Change CATS</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ReduxDeneme;
```

- **1. Scenario**: I have used classic, non-memoized style selectors. There are 6 times console.log on the console. (2 times at first opening - it's normal -, 2 times at clicking "Change Dogs" button, 2 times at clicking "Change Cats" button) . It means 6 times re-rendering happened.
- **2. Scenario**:  I have used `reselect` middleware to prevent unnecessary re-renderings. But, It doesn't work or I have misunderstood meaning of `reselect`.

Could someone explain the correct way or where am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess it is because you redefine the reselect selector each render cycle, which likely triggers the `useSelector` hook, which then return *new* references to objects for cats and dogs passed as props to those components, thus they rerender.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the selectors inside your component. You should do it outside (e.g. somewhere near your reducer).

Currently you are recreating the selector after each render. Here's a better way:

```
// inside reducer.js

  export const petsSel = state => state.pets;
  export const dogsDataMemo = createSelector(
    petsSel,
    pets => pets.dogs
  );
  export const catsDataMemo = createSelector(
    petsSel,
    pets => pets.cats
  );
```

Added a codesandbox with a working example based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-snowflake-5ssrw

To achieve what you desire you need to use React.memo (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) as well:

```
const Dogs = React.memo(({ dogsData }) => {
  console.log("Dogs rendering..");
  return <h1>{dogsData}</h1>;
});
```

Comment: +1 for the splitting up of input selectors. (*But this is the pattern `reselect` uses in their docs anyway*)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't work. It's still keep going re-render. Can you fix my codes to explain detailed please ?

Comment: @tudor.gergely I have moved `Cats` and `Dogs` component to outside of `ReduxDeneme` component. When we create `Cats` and `Dogs` component with `memo`, It works without unnecessary re-rendering. But, I think it's all about `memo`. How can I show `reselect` advantage? I supposed that we can prevent re-render only with `reselect`. If it's possible, can you show me to `reselect` working?

Comment: Reselect is useful when you want to recompute `derived` data: data which is not stored directly into redux but depends on it. It works by only recomputing the selector when its selector changes (first function inside createSelector). What you want to achieve also needs React.memo (otherwise React will always rerender)

Comment: I added full answer. Thanks for your effort @tudor.gergely!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I thank @tudor very much for his efforts. All of his said is correct.

But, I want to show that Reselect works.

**SCENARIO 1 - NON-MEMOIZED**

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
// import { catsDataMemo, dogsDataMemo } from "./selectors";

// Components
const Dogs = memo(({ dogsData }) => {
  console.log("Dogs rendering..");
  return <h1>{dogsData}</h1>;
});

const Cats = memo(({ catsData }) => {
  console.log("Cats rendering..");
  return <h1>{catsData}</h1>;
});

function ReduxDeneme() {
  // Standart useSelector without MEMOIZED
  const dogsData = useSelector(
    state => state.pets.dogs,
    console.log("dogsData Selector çalıştı.")
  );
  const catsData = useSelector(
    state => state.pets.cats,
    console.log("catsData Selector çalıştı.")
  );

  // Actions

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const changeDogs = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_DOGS" });
  const changeCats = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_CATS" });

  const noChangeCats = () =>
    dispatch({ type: "NO_CHANGE_CATS", payload: catsData });

  return (
    <div>
      <Dogs dogsData={dogsData} />
      <Cats catsData={catsData} />
      <button onClick={changeDogs}>Change Dogs</button>
      <button onClick={changeCats}>Change CATS</button>
      <button onClick={noChangeCats}>No Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(ReduxDeneme);
```

**Be Careful!** When you click the "**Change Dogs**" button, output in the console will be:

```
dogsData Selector çalıştı.
catsData Selector çalıştı.
Dogs rendering..
```

or when you click the "**Change Cats**" button, the output will be:

```
dogsData Selector çalıştı.
catsData Selector çalıştı.
Cats rendering..
```

Whatever button you press, both of useSelectors will work as you can see from console.log

**SCENARIO 2 - MEMOIZED WITH RESELECT MIDDLEWARE**

Firstly, we separate memoized selectors to another file as @tudor.gergely mentioned.

> BE CAREFULL! You must define the correct path of an object.

```
// selectors.js

import { createSelector } from "reselect";

export const dogsDataMemo = createSelector(
  state => state.pets.dogs, // BE CAREFULL while defining..
  dogs => {
    console.log("DogsDataMemo has worked.");
    return dogs;
  }
);
export const catsDataMemo = createSelector(
  state => state.pets.cats, // BE CAREFULL while defining..
  cats => {
    console.log("CatsDataMemo has worked.");
    return cats;
  }
);
```

Then, we import this file into main.js file and use again useSelector with our memoized selectors:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { catsDataMemo, dogsDataMemo } from "./selectors";

// Components
const Dogs = memo(({ dogsData }) => {
  console.log("Dogs rendering..");
  return <h1>{dogsData}</h1>;
});

const Cats = memo(({ catsData }) => {
  console.log("Cats rendering..");
  return <h1>{catsData}</h1>;
});

function ReduxDeneme() {
  const dogsData = useSelector(dogsDataMemo);
  const catsData = useSelector(catsDataMemo);

  // Actions
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const changeDogs = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_DOGS" });
  const changeCats = () => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_CATS" });

  const noChangeCats = () =>
    dispatch({ type: "NO_CHANGE_CATS", payload: catsData });

  return (
    <div>
      <Dogs dogsData={dogsData} />
      <Cats catsData={catsData} />
      <button onClick={changeDogs}>Change Dogs</button>
      <button onClick={changeCats}>Change CATS</button>
      <button onClick={noChangeCats}>No Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(ReduxDeneme);
```

and the final output:

- When click the "Change Dogs" button:

```
DogsDataMemo has worked.
Dogs rendering
```

- When click the "Change Cats" button:

```
CatsDataMemo has worked.
Cats rendering..
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use the selector with an identity function (dogs => dogs) as it doesn't really help. Reselect is useful for derived data, as it is mentioned on their website.

Comment: Whats your suggestion to use instead of reselect for basic identity functions?